# Big file stored in GCS server only partialy when served using blob key

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore, google-cloud-storage

I am writing zip files into google cloud storage using GCS client library. Then I retrieve the blob key using create_gs_key() function. Immediately after creating the file I try to download it using a second http request. I write the blob key obtained in the previous call to  X-AppEngine-BlobKey header response.

When the file is relatively big, usually about 30 MB or more, the first try sometimes results in an incomplete file, a few MB smaller than the target size. If you wait a little the next try is usually fine.

I had the same problem when I tried to write files into blobstore using the API that is now deprecated.

Is it guaranteed that when you close the file it should already be available for serving?

Comment: just to double check, u encountered this on app engine server, not on dev appserver. right?

Comment: Yes. This happens on app engine server. So it's a production problem for me.

Comment: When you say "try to download it using a second http request", what library are you using and where are you downloading from?
Also, when you say "incomplete file", do you mean the http response is a 200 with file size smaller than what you expect, or does the connection break?

Comment: My app is python with django running on GAE. I set the 'X-AppEngine-BlobKey' in the response in order to serve the file using the Blobstore API. I get response 200 and the file size is smaller then expected. For example instead of 100MB zip file I get only 92MB. The connection does not break. After a few minutes, when I try to download the file again, it completes without a problem.